# Go to the next row depending on a value from a column in C#

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So, I am trying to update a query starting at a specific row and greater than a row.

```
UPDATE database..table SET PcName = 'TESTE-PC' WHERE row >= 15
```

Before using query:

```
    Column A     Column B
1    Teste1        132
2    Teste1        132
3    Teste1        132
4    Teste1        132
5    Teste1        132
6    Teste1        132
```

With my query I want to update in row 4 to 6 the values from Column

How could I do it?

Comment: Can you please show some sample data and expected result

Comment: if you want a row, you need to sort your query first.

Comment: Can you also define "next row"

Comment: I've updated my post @TheGameiswar

Comment: I've updated my post @fpietka

Comment: And what you have is different line 6 from line 4? It you are in the picture number. If you want to use the number, then enter additional column id, type Int.

Comment: Nothing differentiate your rows, based on what you provided. Update would be random as far as your sql engine is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

The database is not unusual and should know what the "next line". This is an exceptional case. By the line should be treated on a key and unique fields.